# File won't transfer with Post Method

Tags: php, html

So on a page I use:

When I go on upload.php

I can see the file when I do `echo $_Post['file];`

But I can't see it when I do echo `$_FILES["file"]["name"];`

I tryed to print_r the array $_FILES['file']; and the array is empty.

I'm trying to upload a .zip file.

Do you know could be the problem?

This is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="../script/editArticle.php?id=<?php echo $id . "&a=" . $author ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Upload File (.zip):</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="form-control" style="width: 100%">Update your code</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Share your code. It's likely you've forgotten to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` or something similar.

Comment: Your form should contain `enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"` - Plus, just for argument's sake, it's `echo $_POST['file'];` `$_POST` is a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), but I doubt that's what you want to use. Show your full PHP and HTML form. Make sure your input file element is named `name="file"`

Comment: your html............ ?

Comment: As per your edit, show your PHP handler. Plus this `../script/editArticle.php?id=<?php echo $id . "&a=" . $author ?>` is questionable, so we don't know what that is doing. I can say this, that looks to me like a GET method and your PHP has GET instead of POST.

Answer (score 0):

try with this -

```
<form action="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I added the enctype. But I was backing up the page so the enctype wasn't there. Thanks